# Unable to import Python's email module at all

Tags: python, email

I can't seem to import the email module at all. Every time I do it I get an error. I've tried uninstalling Python and reinstalling, but the email module just refuses to work. I've even done "pip install email" and it's still broken. I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium x64, running an x86 version of Python.

Here's what happens:

```
c:\Users\Nicholas\Desktop>python
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:21:10) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import email
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: No module named utils
>>>
```

EDIT: I've tried both Python from python.org and ActivePython, thinking ActivePython might work. Is there anyway to completely remove python and all its data and start 100% fresh maybe?

Comment: Where did you download python from?  It looks like it came from ActiveState, instead of from Python.org, and may not contain all of the libraries.

Comment: can you import other modules?

Comment: got to install py-email,
I had the same problem, as I was not compiling a single line of code by meself, I was merely compiling git.

Answer (score 133):

It looks like you have a file named `email.py`.  Don't use file names that have the same name as Python standard library modules.  Generally, your working directory comes earlier on the Python search path for importing modules so files in your working directory will override modules with the same name in the standard library.

The clue: note the path names in the traceback

```
  File "email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
```

By the way, this is a very common error.  The excellent tutorial in the Python standard documentation set talks about it [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Comment: That must be it. There is no `email.py` in the Python standard library (it's a package, a directory with several submodules).

Comment: If that was the case, be sure to remove email.pyc from your working directory as well.

Comment: All Python modules should be uniquely namespaced somehow to avoid any potential for this kind of failure.  It's faintly ridiculous that you have to somehow know which filenames to avoid using in your own project.

Comment: This is the exactly problem I've got. I execute a script with other named `email.py` and I was always getting the same error. Thanks, Ned!

Comment: I literally had a file called "email.py" on my Desktop. I initiated the Python3 REPL from this directory on my Ubuntu system. This seemed to be the problem.

Comment: Be sure to remove hidden `email.pyc` as well.

Comment: Yup; thanks! I had the same problem and this fixed it :)

Comment: metoo  named the file as email.py, great question and great answer.

Answer (score 40):

I just came across this error and wanted to share my solution. In my case, I had a file named `email.py` in directory. This created a name conflict between Python's `email.py` and my file. When smtplib tried to `import email.utils` it looked and my file and didn't find anything. After I renamed my copy of `email.py` into `myemail.py` everything worked like a charm.

Comment: I have the same problem, however when I renamed mine to Myemail.py it still errored out the same way.

Comment: do not forget to remove `email.pyc` as well!

Comment: I did the same thing!

Answer (score 5):

I also came across this error. In addition to renaming the email.py to something else, you must also *remove* the email.pyc (notice the C) file. After that, all is well. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5):

I also fetched this problem because i had a file named email.py in my project directory. I wasn't able to **import urllib.request** . When i changed the file name email.py to emailtest.py then the error gone away.
In every time we should not use the name what is same as python core file name.

Comment: This is a restatement of the two highest voted answers

Answer (score 0):

If none of the posted solution works, try the following:

(Use the combo python3 / pip3 OR python / pip and try not to mix those)

1. Delete your current virtual environment directory.
2. Create new virtual environment and activate it with 'source'.
3. If exist, run the <pip install -r requirements.txt>.
4. Install any missing packages with pip or pip3.
5. Run the application to see if that solved the problem.

Answer (score -17):

```
npm install email
```

has fix my problem, try it.