# Import email.utils Library in Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

In my `Python` application, I called the `smtplib.py` (Python library) to send email. But it fails at importing `email.util` as follow

[image: Utils importing error]

However, when running Python from command line, I can import the `email.utils` without error.

[image: Util imported successfully]

**Note: This only happens in my Windows Machine. The code runs well in my Ubuntu**

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshot images of text here. Plain text (in a code block, if necessary to retain formatting) is **much** better.

Comment: I cannot copy the text from the command line and it's not a good idea to re-type the text. Can you tell me how I can copy the text in such windows?

Comment: I rarely use Windows these days, but [this article](http://windows7themes.net/en-us/how-to-copy-text-from-command-prompt/) looks helpful. Apparently, there's also a _QuickEdit Mode_.

Comment: Long shot, but could you try running the python command line program from the directory containing exgui.py and then run 'import exgui'?

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be you have different versions of python running. You could adding this to your script:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

and executing the same code from the command line to check if the python versions match.

EDIT:

Another reason could be you have a file named email.py in the same folder as your other script, see [Unable to import Python's email module at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861818/unable-to-import-pythons-email-module-at-all)

This should probably be a comment, but I don't have enough rep...

Comment: Thanks for your comment! but the versions are the same. I am using Python 2.7.8 and I dont have any file named `email.py` in the folder. The only file that I am running is `exgui.py`