# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client' python dropbox api

Tags: python, dropbox

I'm starting with the python api dropbox ,I've copied the first example but I get an  error

```
import dropbox

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
app_key = 'MY_APP_KEY'
app_secret = 'MY_APP_SECRET'

flow = dropbox.client.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(app_key, app_secret)
```

the dropbox object has not a client atribute but it's the same code  of the documentation.

the traceback

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/PycharmProjects/api/dropbox.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/api/dropbox.py", line 3, in <module>
    import dropbox
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/api/dropbox.py", line 9, in <module>
    flow = dropbox.client.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(app_key, app_secret)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

Comment: I would like to see the documentation. Got a link?

Comment: Can you give us the full traceback? Is your script called `dropbox.py` by any chance?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/python

Comment: Look closely at your traceback; Python is not importing the SDK but your own script; `/home/user/PycharmProjects/api/dropbox.py` ran the line `import dropbox` which then moves on to `/home/user/PycharmProjects/api/dropbox.py` again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to import Python's email module at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861818/unable-to-import-pythons-email-module-at-all)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have called your own script `dropbox.py`, you need to rename your script and delete any `dropbox.pyc` file. You are trying to import from your local file not the `dropbox` module.