# module 'pickle' has no attribute 'dump'

Tags: python, pickle

```
import pickle

imelda = ('More Mayhem',
          'IMelda May',
          '2011',
          ((1, 'Pulling the Rug'),
           (2, 'Psycho'),
           (3, 'Mayhem'),
           (4, 'Kentish Town Waltz')))

with open("imelda.pickle", "wb") as pickle_file:
    pickle.dump(imelda, pickle_file)
```

I am trying to execute this code, but the console keeps telling me:

```
module 'pickle' has no attribute 'dump'
```

Do I have to install pickle via pip? I am not sure what is happening here.

Comment: I can run your code fine in my computer.

Comment: My psychic powers are telling me that you have a file named `pickle.py` in your current directory, making this a duplicate of [Unable to import Python's email module at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6861818/744178)

Comment: `print(dir(pickle))` to show the accuracy of jwodder's psychic powers. Always `print` everything you don't understand.

Comment: Pretty sure @jwodder is right... If right after the `import pickle` you add the line `print(pickle.__file__)` and run the code what do you see?

Comment: Yes, I did indeed have my file name picckle.py. Thanks for your psychic help @jwodder

Answer (score 49):

Happened to me too. I had a file called `pickle.py` in my current directory. Just rename it and it's fixed :)

Comment: Fail, I created a file called pickle to manage the pickle operations.

Answer (score 5):

You might have used your Python file name as `pickle.py`. Python interpreter is confused and looking for dump function in you file `pickle.py` instead of the package you have imported. Change the name of your file to something else, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have file name is pickle.py and any files also saved for this name like pickle.py then remove it first. Then after,save file with other name like pikkle.py instead of pickle.py. your code will be execute.

Answer (score 0):

just check your file name.
if it is pickle.py, then I recommend you to change your file name. instead rename as pickle1.py
it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a file name problem. You wrote dumps as dump. Try it with dumps.

Comment: `dumps` is used for dumping string, `dump` is used for files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30738571)