# Cannot import "pickle" to a script in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am currently learning python and was intruduced to pickle.
I tried to import it in pycharm but the statement remaned grey even after the statement was "used" (I added a dump() statement). I then went into the pycharm project interpreter settings where pip and setuptools was already installed. Then I tried to add "pickle" but there weren´t any results showing for it when searching. I had the same trouble with "turtle" some time ago. What could be the reasons for that?
That´s my code:

```
import pickle
file = open("D:\Data\...", "wb")
number = 12
dump(number, file)
file.close()
```

Comment: Could you post some code

Comment: Does the code run properly or is just that it stays grey?

Comment: It does not run properly and stays gray. For thr error message see below.

Comment: `import pickle` makes exactly one name available to your code: `pickle` itself.  It does NOT give you all of the individual names defined in the pickle module, such as `dump`.  You have to write those as `pickle.dump`, or change the import to something like `from pickle import dump`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but now I get the following error: AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pickle' has no attribute 'dump' (most likely due to a circular import)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already said this in the comments, but I figured it's easier to put in an actual answer.
You have three options. The first is to replace the `dump()` with `pickle.dump()`. This is what I'd recommend, but you can also replace the import with `from pickle import dump` or add the line `dump = pickle.dump` before you call `dump()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but now I get the following error: AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pickle' has no attribute 'dump' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: Do you have any other files named pickle?

Comment: I have found the solution. Shouldn´t have named my file "pickle.py". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087036/module-pickle-has-no-attribute-dump

Answer (score 1):

pickle is part of the Python standard library, which means you don't have to install anything via `pip`, you should be able to just do `import pickle`.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not able to just import pickle. That´s the problem.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your Python installation, what error are you getting?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Data/...", line 1, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "D:\Data\...", line 4, in <module>
    dump(number, file)
NameError: name 'dump' is not defined